# Limit array elements based on next key or previous key?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of thumbnails similar to:

```
$thumbnails = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

First I want to apply a limit of 6 based on current `key = 3` so the so the array should return: `3,4,5,6,7,8`.

If I press the next link the array should return:`4,5,6,7,8,9`;

If I press previous link the array should return: `2,3,4,5,6,7`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice):

```
$start = 3; $limit = 6;
$limited = array_slice( $thumbnails, $start - 1, $limit);
```

Comment: I like this one better than Jay's because you don't damage the initial array, so you won't need to rebuild it.